# cannot read properties of undefined(reading"name")

Tags: javascript, node.js

I trying to make a survey website and I have been stuck on this bug for hours. I have a from that has 5 inputs and it takes name, question and 4 options as text and submits them. when clicking on submit button the server recieves a post method with the action /all after getting /all the server should render all.ejs. below is my index.js file:

```
router.post('/all', function (req, res) {


const newsurvey=new survey({

"name":req.body.name,
"question":req.body.question,
"option1":req.body.option1,
"option2": req.body.option2,
"option3":req.body.option3,
"option4": req.body.option4,



 }) 
  survey.create(newsurvey)
  console.log(newsurvey)
  console.log(req.body.name)
  res.render('all', { title: 'All Surveys', survey});
});
// initializing a new survey object
router.get('/addsurvey', function (req, res, next) {
  survey.find((err, list)=>{
    const newsurvey = new survey({
    "name":"",
    "question":"", 
    "option1":"",
    "option2":"",
    "option3":"",
    "option4":""
  }
)}
  
  ,res.render('surdetails', { title: 'Details', survey})
  
  );
  
});
router.get('/all', function (req, res) {
  survey.find((err, list)=>{
    if (err){
      return console.error(err);
    }else{
      res.render('all', { title: 'All Surveys', survey: survey });

    }
  })
  
});
```

and below is my all.ejs file which returns cannot read properties of undefined(reading"name"):

```
<tbody>
    <!-- Template Row -->
    <% for (let count = 0; count < survey.length; count++) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= survey[count].name %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= survey[count].name %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= survey[count].question %></td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" value="<%= survey[count].option1 %>">
        <label for="option1"><%= survey[count].option1 %></label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="option2" name="option2" value="<%= survey[count].option2 %>">
        <label for="option2"><%= survey[count].option2 %></label><br>  
        <input type="radio" id="option3" name="option3" value="<%= survey[count].option3 %>">
        <label for="option3"><%= survey[count].option3 %></label><br><br>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        
        <a href="/delete/<%= survey[count]._id %>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a>
      </td>

     
    </tr>
    <% } %>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: I assume this is using `express.js`? Have you defined middleware to parse JSON request bodies like this `app.use(express.json())` in your app? Can you also provide which line exactly you get the error? The error is basicly saying that you want to accesss property called `name` on something that is `undefined`. You could potentially do this multiple times in your app e.g. in your `all` route. Does `req.body` contain what you expect it to? My guess would be it does not.

Comment: Your code is quite strange... you `post` on your endpoint '/all', you `get` on your endpoint '/addsurvey', you render the `survey` object while it seems to be a global object, etc. Are you sure you posted your actual code?

Comment: @Ben im pretty new to node.js and express but yes this is the actual code

Comment: Try to log `req.body`. I believe it is `undefined`. If that's the case it's probably because you don't have a JSON parser defined as middleware using `app.use(express.json())`. Without that express will not be able to parse JSON. It would also be helpful if you provide the JSON request body which you are using when accesssing the `/all` route.

Comment: @Mushroomator req.body returns: 
[Object: null prototype] {
  name: 'model',
  question: 'as',
  option1: 'sd',
  option2: 'sad',
  option3: 'asd',
  option4: 'sad'
}

and the values are my inputs

Comment: Ok that's good. So you should be able to access `name` in the request body. Where does the error happen? Which line? In the template or the JavaScript? You are also trying to access `name` in your template and as we don't now what your variable `survey` holds which you pass to the template engine, the problem might be there. It also needs to have a `name` property.

Comment: @Mushroomator survey is a Mongod db connection. I am able to create and insert to the database but I cant see them in the code above... the error happens at :
 <td><%= survey[count].name %></td>

Comment: You should use `console.log(survey)` right before you call `res.render()`.